# React: Persisting state in tabs

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a react thing with tabs. Each tab has it's own state that I need to persist between tab changes, but when I switch tabs I lose it.

Currently when I'm adding a new tab I do something like this:

```
var tab = <Tab hash={hash} />
this.setState({
    tabs: this.state.tabs.concat([tab]),
    tab: this.state.tabs.length
});
```

And when I render I do something like this:

```
var tab = null;
if (this.state.tab !== null)
    tab = this.state.tabs[this.state.tab];
return ( <div>{tab}</div> );
```

Another question suggests passing a boolean to decide whether to display it or not, but as far as I can see, there's no way to do it this way.

Comment: show more code please, what is your main element? you can save state in parent for every tab and pass it as `prop` to childs

Comment: Yes but I don't want to do that, as 90% of the state (And half the code) in the entire app would end up in the top level component. (Example: Now I have to store the contents of every input in every tab in the state of the *topmost* component just so I can put them back after switching tabs.)

Comment: sounds like you need something like --> https://github.com/reactjs/redux

Comment: Never looked at it before, but a quick glance leads me to believe this is the same as storing all my state in a global var with syntactic sugar..

Comment: @JV It is. But you also get a well defined architecture for deriving state from actions in a functional, subscribable, optimized way for free. There's a reason it's the most popular Flux implementation for React.

Comment: You don't have to store the tab state in the topmost component of your app, just a parent of the tabs ("tabgroup" or something).

Comment: should you return {tabs} instead of {tab}?

Answer (score 0):

So a simple solution would be something when we store the state globally.

```
const tabStates  = [tabstate1 ,tabstate2 ]
```

Whenever there is an update do

```
 tabStates[tabIndex] = 'newState'
```